# Ranking each column from higher to lower

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset which shows the accuracy values obtained by different method across different datasets. Each row represents one dataset. The dataframe looks like this:

```
Method_1   Method_2   Method_3   Method_4
  84.3       82.1       90.7       73.5
  82.1       79.8       83.3       60.2
  84.2       88.5       90.1       95.3
```

I need to rank each row (from 1 to 4) so that 1 is the highest or larges value and 4 in the lowest value.

So the output should be like this:

```
Method_1   Method_2   Method_3   Method_4
   2          3          1          4
   2          3          1          4
   4          3          2          1
```

Any idea how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with `ascending=False`:

```
df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False).convert_dtypes()
```

*NB. in case of ties, use the `method` parameter to set up the desired option (min/max/average/first/dense)*

output:

```
   Method_1  Method_2  Method_3  Method_4
0         2         3         1         4
1         2         3         1         4
2         4         3         2         1
```